# Как убрать обводку символов в VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

VsCode стал обводить русские символы выборочно жёлтой рамкой. Как это убрать? Это не поиск по проекту, не поиск через <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

[image: кусок кода]

Comment: Если подвести мышь к обведенному символу что-нибудь покажет?

Comment: нет, ничего не происходит ни при наведении ни при нажатии

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как я и предполагал, что где-то есть правило, которое подсвечивает символы, которые можно спутать с английскими по типу русской и английской "а"/"a".

Решение:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. В поиске пишем "ui".
3. Переходим в настройки ui.
4. В поиске настроек пишем "Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters"
5. Убираем галочку

[image: rule]

Comment: Эта фишка [появилась](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_unicode-highlighting) в версии 1.63 (подсветка включается, если вы посчитали исходники ненадежными)

Answer (score 0):

У меня та же беда была, только подчеркивало абсолютно все символы кириллицы.
Ни один способ отключить ее не помогал, на английском стаковерфлоу тоже.
Единственное, что помогло:

Файл settings.json: находим `editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters` и прописываем в него все символы.

```
"А": true, "Б": true, "В": true, "Г": true, "Д": true, "Е": true, "Ё": true, 
"Ж": true, "З": true, "И": true, "Й": true, "К": true, "Л": true, "М": true, 
"Н": true, "О": true, "П": true, "Р": true, "С": true, "Т": true, "У": true,
"Ф": true, "Х": true, "Ц": true, "Ч": true, "Ш": true, "Щ": true, "Ъ": true,
"Ы": true, "Ь": true, "Э": true, "Ю": true, "Я": true, "а": true, "б": true, 
"в": true, "г": true, "д": true, "е": true, "ё": true, "ж": true, "з": true, 
"и": true, "й": true, "к": true, "л": true, "м": true, "н": true, "о": true, 
"п": true, "р": true, "с": true, "т": true, "у": true, "ф": true, "х": true, 
"ц": true, "ч": true, "ш": true, "щ": true, "ъ": true, "ы": true, "ь": true, 
"э": true, "ю": true, "я": true, "ї": true, "Ї": true, "і": true, "І": true,
```