# Отключить проверку на орфографию VS-CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Не коректно работает проверка на ошибки. Не дает форматировать код и подчеркивает слова...
Возможно какойто хот кей зацепил(

[image: Ошибки в словах]

Comment: посмотрите плагины, может у вас что-то похожее на Russian - Code Spell Checker

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [VS CODE, Подсвечивание кириллицы в html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365801/vs-code-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-html)

Comment: Также: [Как убрать обводку символов в VsCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1359498)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать обводку символов в VsCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359498/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-vscode)

Comment: Знайшов відповідь яка вирішила моя проблему [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359498/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-vscode)