# VS CODE, Подсвечивание кириллицы в html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Недавно в vs code появилась такая проблема: при вводе кириллицы, текст начал подсвечиваться желтым. Как это можно убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наведите на них курсор и там будет функция никогда не подсвечивать

Answer (score 2):

1. Наведите курсор на подсвечивающиеся символы
2. Нажмите на Adjust Settings
3. Disable highlighting of non-basic ASCII characters.

[image: Изображение]

Comment: не работает, у вас на скриншоте эта функция включена и она выделяет все слова, и вы её отключили и у вас стало нормально всё, а у меня же подсвечиваются буквы по отдельности как на скриншоте в вопросе при этом эта функция уже выключена

Answer (score 2):

Надо убрать галочку возле: *Editor -> Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters*

Answer (score 2):

Немного расширю ответ от @headbang1ng.

Первое, если владете английским, то вам может помочь данный [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138898) на github.

Второе, здесь ниже конкретный мануал, как добраться до настройки:

1. В интерфейсе VSCode нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Введите `settings`, в появившейся строке, и выберите `Preferences: Open User Settings`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В строку поиска в верху окна начните вводить `unicode highlight`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Снять галочку с `Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters`

Answer (score 2):

Совсем недавно появился ещё один способ решения: добавление `ru`-локали в список `"allowedLocales"`.

В настройках нужно сделать поиск по `editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales`, далее нажать <kbd>Add Item</kbd> и добавить локаль `ru` со значением `true`, как на картинке:

[image: editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales Add Item]

Это отключает подсветку подозрительных символов, но только из русской локали. Очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо зайти в настройки, *ctrl+*, в поиске найти **ASCII**
Выключить off

[image: Выключить off]

Так же советую поставить 2 плагина для проверки орфографии

1.Code Spell Checker
Включить ru,en
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2.Russian - Code Spell Checker

Comment: Не понятно при чем тут вообще проверка орфографии

Answer (score -1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убрать галочку! Должно помочь однозначно

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ошибки правописания расширение Code Spell не так выделяет: оно подчеркивает проблемные слова волной целиком, а не отдельные буквы обводит.